# using tcpdump for findng out the reason for Websocket disconnect

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

In our Application we are facing some web socket disconnects , but don't know  whats causing that disconnect on web socket .

So for this reason i was using tcpdump for debugging the network traffic flowing

I ran the tcpdump with as

```
sudo tcpdump -n -s 1500 -X src host mywebsite.com -S
```

It displayed the following output

```
23:47:57.653107 IP 122.222.4.2.80 > 183.82.171.6.40025: Flags [P.], seq 833296683:833297760, ack 2581941127, win 6710, length 1077
    0x0000:  4500 045d c95f 4000 2f06 4657 ce84 0707  E..]._@./.FW....
    0x0010:  b752 ab06 0050 9c59 31ab 192b 99e5 4b87  .R...P.Y1..+..K.
```

As this being a web socket application the data will be dumped contonously .

I am completely new to tcpdump and networking .
My question is that In case there is a disconnect , how can i know whats caused that with the above information ??

thank you in advance